# In Python, How do I make my conditional if loop not execute if input is valid?

Tags: python, validation, loops, input

```
#Write a short program that will do the following
#Set a value your favorite number between 0 and 100
#Ask the user to guess your favorite number between 0 and 100
#Repeat until they guess that number and tell them how many tries it took
#If the value they guessed is not between 0 and 100
#tell the user invalid guess and do not count that as an attempt
```

My problem is that even if the user guesses a number between 0 and 100, it still prints out the "Invalid guess. Try again". How do I control my loop to skip past the print statement and question repeat if it's acceptable input(1-100)? Thanks in advance!

```
favoriteNumber = 7
attempts = 0

guess = raw_input("Guess a number between 0 and 100: ")

if (guess  < 0) or (guess > 100):
    print "Invalid guess. Try again"
    guess = raw_input("Guess a number between 0 and 100: ")

attempts1 = str(attempts)
print "it took " + attempts1 + "attempts."
```

Comment: What loop? There's no loop anywhere in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use input and not raw_input,so you get integer and not string

```
favoriteNumber = 7
attempts = 0


while True:
    guess = input("Guess a number between 0 and 100: ")
    if (guess  < 0) or (guess > 100):

        attempts=attempts+1
        print "Invalid guess. Try again"
    else:
        attempts=attempts+1
        break

attempts1 = str(attempts)
print "it took " + attempts1 + " attempts."
```

Comment: thanks a lot to everyone, but you helped me the most.

Answer (score 0):

In Python 2.7.10 it appears that if you do not convert a string to an integer, it accepts it but all rules that apply to numbers return false.
Here is a working example:

```
favoriteNumber = 7
attempts = 0

guess = raw_input("Guess a number between 0 and 100: ")

if (int(guess)  < 0) or (int(guess) > 100):
    print "Invalid guess. Try again"
    guess = raw_input("Guess a number between 0 and 100: ")

attempts1 = str(attempts)
print "it took " + attempts1 + " attempts."
```

In Python 3.4 the original code yields an error where it tells you that it is a string instead of an integer. But, like Paul said you could put raw_input inside of an int() command.

Answer (score 0):

you raw_input returns a string, which is always `>` 100.  Cast it to a number with `int(raw_input())`